# Can an object be a field?

Tags: c#, object, field

From [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/type) page:

> Type objects can be stored as fields and static fields.

This has confused me. I thought fields were just variables (like int, string, etc.) encapsulated within a class or an object. Can objects be fields too?

Comment: You mean can a field be an object, yes

Comment: @Ahmad No, a field can't be an "object". it can be a reference to an object.

Comment: Yes, they can. anything can be a field.

Comment: @xanatos then what is an object? In C# as you declare a referenced type object, it is a reference to an object or simply an object, because object can't be accessed or declared without that reference (it has no meaning). By the way, he should say can a filed be an object.

Comment: @Ahmad An object can exist without references. If you do `new Foo()` and then ignore the reference, the GC will clean the object only when it runs, so for some seconds the object exists without references. You can see it if the object has a finalizer.

Comment: 'object' is an ill-defined term. Sometimes it is meant to mean 'class' and sometimes 'instance'. In C# it usually means a type, to be precise the base class for all other classes. This shorthand speaking is normal in OOP, an integer is an integer etc..

Answer (score 3):

Sure an object can be a field in a class.

Imagine a class

```
class ClassA
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
}

class ClassB
{

   public ClassA ObjA;
}
```

Now `ClassB` has a field `ObjA` which is an object of `ClassA`

> I thought fields were just variables (like int, string, etc.)
>   encapsulated within a class or an object.

It is not specific to *primitive* types, You can have object of a class/struct as field *(or properties)*  in your class.

Comment: Which is a reference to an object of ClassA

Comment: @xanatos, yes, but it is just semantics IMO, `ObjA` is a reference to an object of `ClassA` or it is an object.

Comment: the map to something can't be the something. While you are trying to simplify the concept, I do think that when you simplify you should be very careful with words, so to not create false ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Anything can be a field. In C#, every type (including the `Type` type) is a child of `object`. So you can create anything you'd like and make that a (static) field of any class.

Comment: *every type* nearly every type... `int*` for example isn't

Comment: @xanatos `typeof(int*)` returns `System.Int32*`?

Comment: @DionV. Look at `typeof(int*).BaseType` and then look at `typeof(int).BaseType`, then try doing `List<int*>`

Comment: @xanatos: Yeah, `unsafe` blocks tend to break a lot of normal assumptions about C#. But I don't think it's worth telling that to newbies, it's a lot of confusion for a feature most people will hardly ever use, if at all.

Comment: @SolalPirelli As I've said to Habib, it's the right thing to simplify the concept... The trick is in selecting the words. In C# nearly every type is a child of `object` is completely true, has the same verbosity and offers the reader a glimpse of what else there is. Just for curiosity, without going on the `unsafe` world... `ref int` is a type but isn't a child of object. `typeof(int).MakeByRefType().BaseType`

Answer (score 1):

That article is simplifying a bit. A field/variable/parameter can be a value type (an `int` for example), or a reference to a reference type (informally called an "object"... class types and delegates for example).

`Type` is a reference type (somewhere there is some code like `public class Type { ... }`), so you can put a reference to it in a field/variable/parameter.

Comment: I am confused, this answer looks right to me, but all other answers are saying the opposite thing

Comment: @adoomedknight The point is in the comment of Taw *'object' is an ill-defined term. Sometimes it is meant to mean 'class' and sometimes 'instance'. In C# it usually means a type, to be precise the base class for all other classes. This shorthand speaking is normal in OOP, an integer is an integer etc.* and in the fact that when speaking object (as in instance), reference to an object, object type are all named in the same way. There is a fine point between them. I'm pointing at it.

Comment: so am I right if I say a field can only either be a value type or a reference to a reference type?

Comment: @adoomedknight or it can be an unsafe pointer :-) But yes, you are right :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Type` is a class that describes a type. You can have fields of type `Type` which can then be assigned `Type` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the main question let see first, ***what is field?***

As per msdn

> Fields are objects or values contained in a class or struct. **Fields
>   allow classes and structures to encapsulate data.**

**Example**

```
public class CalendarDate
{
    public int month;
    public int day;
    public int year;
}
```

Important point about field is, it helps classes to encapsulate data. Here in above example month, day, and year are fields which encapsulate month, day, and year data respectively.

Same goes for **Types** also. Classes can use Types to encapsulate data. Only difference is you not know what's that data going to be at compile time because it can be anything of that Type.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all `types` derive from an `object`.  Which is incredibly important, as it will play into the conceptual notion of *Boxing* and *Unboxing*.

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR
>   boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and
>   stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from
>   the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit. The concept of
>   boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system
>   in which a value of any type can be treated as an object.

An example would be the following:

```
// Implicit Boxing Operation:
int i = 123;
object o = i;

// Explicit Boxing Operation:
int i = 123;
object o = (object)i;
```

Understanding this concept is important, as it will illuminate context like *@Habib* illustrated in his answer.  This is where I feel the gap is in your understanding.

Your misnomer of encapsulation, in several instances a `field` becomes encapsulated in a `property`.  So when you see:

```
public string Example { get; set; }
```

That would represent an encapsulated field.